# is my understanding of the following code correct?

Tags: lua

suppose I have a file with name myFileName.lua, which contains the following code.

```
function Set(source)
  set = {}
  if source then
    for i,v in ipairs(source) do
      set[v] = true
    end
  end
  return set
end

return Set
```

My understanding is as the following: source is a table structure. `if source then` means, if the table `source` is not empty, then do something. The first return set means returning the table set as the return value of the function Set. The second return Set means, returning Set function as the return value of this file myFileName.lua.

Then, in file main.lua, I have 
Set = require('lib/myFileName')

This means, the Set function in the file myFile.lua is returned and assigned the name Set, so that I can use it in the file main.lua. Is this correct? Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if source then means, if the table source is not empty` - It means "if the table source is provided", because the argument might be skipped: `x=Set()`

Comment: `set` shoutd be a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the file, `Set` is a function. `set` is a table. The `if source then` line will just make sure `source` is not `nil` or `false`. so even if source is `{}` empty, it will enter.

All of the rest is correct, requiring the file from main would give you access to the `Set` function.

For more information you can [read further about logical expressions in Lua here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ExpressionsTutorial)